# Implementing delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to delay execution of script in a loop. After reviewing multiple queries and answers I am overwhelmed with information and seem unable to sort it out. Wandering through answers relative to 'setInterval', and 'setTimeout' it seemed to me that 'setTimeout' was the appropriate method of implementing the desired delay.

What I want to do is have a loop draw a set of lines and return to the beginning of the loop were it will wait for a defined period (about 250 mSec - 1000 mSec), then wipe the screen, increment the value setting the position where one line is drawn and draw the next line in the new position.

Single stepping through the code using Firefox's debugger the process can be observed to occur. However when the code is executed outside the debugger a delay occurs and only the line for the last increment of the code is drawn. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

The code is listed below:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
scrndrw();

function scrndrw() {
    for (var angle = 1; angle < 361; angle++) {
        setTimeout(scrndrwdel(), 1000);

        function scrndrwdel() {
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(300, 300);
            ctx.lineTo((((Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180))) * 250) + 300), (((Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180))) * 250) + 300));
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.stroke();
            ringdraw();

            function ringdraw() {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(300, 300, (50 * i), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">
```

Comment: Try with `setTimeout(scrndrwdel, 1000)`

Comment: Try removing the `()` around your function call inside the `setTimeout` call, so it looks like this: `setTimeout(scrndrwdel, 1000);`.

Comment: When I remove the parens  single stepping in the browser debugger does not enter the brackets with the statements to draw the lines. Not sure why this is occurring as examples match your response about not including the parens. Without the parens the screen fails to draw when run outside the debugger. In the debugger it just keeps looping between the setTimeout line and the function scrndrwdel(). Never sequences into the bracketed code. I do appreciate the lead.

Comment: What's the point of a `setTimeout` **inside** the loop? This basically sets up 360 timers, each of them fire in the very same time, 1s after the page is loaded.

Comment: Ok, I obviously am not understanding the setTimeout function. My impression was  setTimeout would delay the execution of the code for the specified time (1000mSec) and then run through the code. It will return to the loop upon completion of the bracketed code and sequence again through the code with another 1000 mSec delay. I did not realize all 360 instances of the delay would fire at the same time. Is there a function which will iterate the delay as opposed to firing all at once?

Comment: are you expecting the circle to complete slowly like the tick of the clock?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to draw, and in what time frame?

Comment: A line of specified radius is drawn from the specified co-ordinates, then five circles with increasing radius are drawn. After a specified delay the screen is wiped clean, the radial line is incremented to the next position and the circles redrawn. This is repeated 360 times. The specified time of 1000 mSec appearing in the code is to allow observation of the process during development. Once solid, the time will be decreased and the number of radial lines increased to deal with visual latency of the eye.

Comment: @MelBlanc: no, there isn't a function that "iterates the delay". You just set the timer, the function fires and at the end of it you set up another timer. As for understanding what happens, you definitely need a good material on that, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I am off to view the video now.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a radar?

Comment: @DJDaveMark Yes. Nest step is to insert code to grab data from FPGA which processes the RF signal.

Answer (score 1):

After viewing the various recommended sites it became apparent the easy way was to use 'setInterval'. The code was rewritten as shown below. The code runs, draws the screen, and waits until it is triggered again by 'setInterval'. The code is triggered to re-run every 2 mSec.

If I understand correctly methods such as 'pause', 'wait' etc found in other languages will not work as it locks the browser until the timeout ends.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var angle = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

draw_line();
setInterval(draw_line, 2);

function draw_line() {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(300, 300);
    ctx.lineTo((((Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180))) * 250) + 300), (((Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180))) * 250) + 300));
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";
    ctx.stroke();

    // ctx.arc(150, 150, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    // ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
    // ctx.stroke();

    if (angle < 360) {
        angle = angle + 0.25;
    } else {
        angle = 0;
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(300, 300, (50 * i), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">
```

Comment: Tip: after 48hrs you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can made this for example :

```js
function send () {
 console.log('OK');
  setTimeout(send, 10000);
}

setTimeout(send, 1000);
```

The first run of the `setTimeout` function is executing after that he running the `console.log` and again the `setTimeout` function, with a new delay inside :)

Comment: There is a component to do things like this: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#imagebitmap

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Will wade through it and see if I can comprehend what is occurring.